# biopython MuscleCommandLine

Tags: linux, python-3.x, biopython

I am using BioPython MuscleCommanLine to align sequences in a subprocess.  The input and output from muscle is stdin and stdout.  This works but as soon as popen calls muscle I get a program summary from muscle on the screen.  This is slowing the program down greatly because there are millions of calls to the subprocess.

```
mcline = MuscleCommandline()
read_list = (SeqRecord(Seq(seq, IUPAC.unambiguous_dna), str(index)) for index, seq in enumerate(grouped_reads_list))

muscle = Popen(str(mcline), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

SeqIO.write(read_list, muscle.stdin, "fasta")  # Send sequences to Muscle in FASTA format.
muscle.stdin.close()

align = AlignIO.read(muscle.stdout, "fasta")  # Capture output from muscle and get it into FASTA format in an object.
print(align)
muscle.stdout.close()
exit("Testin Testing")

consensus_read = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(align).dumb_consensus(threshold=0.6, ambiguous="N", consensus_alpha=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)  # Create consensus from alignment object.
```

The screen output is

MUSCLE v3.8.31 by Robert C. Edgar

http://www.drive5.com/muscle
This software is donated to the public domain.
Please cite: Edgar, R.C. Nucleic Acids Res 32(5), 1792-97.

- 2 seqs, max length 133, avg  length 133
  00:00:00    10 MB(-1%)  Iter   1  100.00%  K-mer dist pass 1
  00:00:00    10 MB(-1%)  Iter   1  100.00%  K-mer dist pass 2
  00:00:00    12 MB(-1%)  Iter   1  100.00%  Align node
  00:00:00    12 MB(-1%)  Iter   1  100.00%  Root alignment
- 6 seqs, max length 133, avg  length 133
  SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 2 rows and 133 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am listing this as an answer instead of editing my question because someone might find it useful.  If I have made an error please let me know.  The problem appears to be with using the BioPython MuscleCommandLine wrapper in this fashion.  I was not able to pass any command line options to muscle through the wrapper when calling through a subprocess.  My modified code for this is below.

```
cmd = ['muscle', "-quiet", "-maxiters", "1", "-diags"]

read_list = (SeqRecord(Seq(seq, IUPAC.unambiguous_dna), str(index)) for index, seq in enumerate(grouped_reads_list))

muscle = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

SeqIO.write(read_list, muscle.stdin, "fasta")  # Send sequences to Muscle in FASTA format.
muscle.stdin.close()

align = AlignIO.read(muscle.stdout, 'fasta')  # Capture output from muscle and get it into FASTA format in an object.

muscle.stdout.close()

consensus_read = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(align).dumb_consensus(threshold=0.6, ambiguous="N", consensus_alpha=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
return str(consensus_read)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe using muscle directly is a better choice if there is anything unexpected when Aligning sequences via BioPython. In either way, it should be easy enough to do the MSA. But using Biopython may be a little more troubling.